# My code doesn't work in Partial View(ascx)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         alert("dd");
         //Attach cascading behavior to the orderID select element.
         $("#orderID").CascadingDropDown("#customerID", '/Home/AsyncOrders',
            {
                promptText: '-- Pick an Order--',
                onLoading: function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#ff3");
                },
                onLoaded: function () {
                    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 300);
                }
            });

         //Attach cascading behavior to the orderDetails select element.
         $("#orderDetails").CascadingDropDown("#orderID", '/Sales/AsyncOrderDetails',
            {
                promptText: '-- Pick an Order Detail --',
                onLoading: function () {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#ff3");
                },
                onLoaded: function () {
                    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 300);

                }
            });

         //When an order detail is selected, fetch the details using ajax
         //and display inside a div tag.
         $('#orderDetails').change(function () {
             if ($(this).val() != '') {
                 $.post('/Sales/OrderDetails', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                     $('#orderDetailsContainer').html(data).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
                 });
             }
         });
     });
    </script>

      <div id="searchFilter">
        Custom text in select lists, lists highlight when loading.<br />
        <%:Html.DropDownList("customerID", Model, "-- Select Customer --")%>
         <%--   <%:Html.DropDownList("cites", ViewData["xml"] as SelectList , "-- Select Customer --")%>--%>
        <select id="orderID" name="orderID">
        </select>
        <select id="orderDetails" name="orderDetails">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="orderDetailsContainer">
    </div>
```

and when write it in page(aspx) very god run

but when use Partial View (ascx) do not run code ?

Comment: Add more details about what doesn't work and how you render partial view

Comment: hi this code use fore cascading dropdownlist wich first show list unit and when change it other drodownlist  show cites of this unit .when use this code in page (aspx) run very god but when use Partial VIew (ascx) do not run

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do it either like this

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("YourUserControl"); %>
```

or (note the colon (:) )

```
<%: Html.Partial("YourUserControl"); %>
```

Or your partial view will not be written to the document